# Match sequential digits

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that can match sequential digits in a string that can also contains letters, such:

ae12 / aeg12345km / mea65 / ab2d43a21 / poe09ac etc.

The string should have sequential digits, which means any digit that are beside and in a sequence (12 is sequential, 1a2 is not sequential, 09 is sequential, a0b0 is not sequential, 00 is not sequential, 11 is not sequential, 112 is sequential)

I went on a couple of topics and it doesn't seem to be possible using regex.

I created this function but I'm not totally satisfied with it, I'd like to improve it:

```
containsSequentialDigits: function (str) {
    var array = str.split('');
    var previousC = null;
    return array.some(function (c) {
        if (isNaN(c)) {
            previousC = null;
            return false;
        }
        if (c === previousC+1 || c === previousC-1 ||
            c === 0 && previousC === 9 || c === 9 && previousC === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        previousC = c;
        return false;
    });
}
```

Do you have any suggestion to simplify it?

Thanks

Comment: Why is it impossible with a regular expression? What is the expected outcome? What is the rules for a pass/fail?

Comment: According to your code, it seems like ab12323 will also be valid.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if two digits are beside and sequential, it should return true

Comment: I edited the topic with additional examples

Comment: @tilix: what exactly do you mean by *sequential*? Do you mean any two digits where the right one is greater than the left one? What about `90` or `910` -- is overflow possible or: can anything following a `9` be sequential?

Comment: 12, 21, 90, 09, 45 are considered sequential. 11, 13, 08, 24 are not considered sequential. So basically two digits where the right one is +1 or -1 the left one and considering 90 and 09 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this regular expresion should work

```
/(0[19]|1[20]|2[31]|3[42]|4[53]|5[64]|6[75]|7[86]|8[97]|9[08])/
```

Comment: This accepts e.g. `24` although `4 != 2+1` and `4 != 2-1`. See comments on question: `24` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also pretty sure a regex will do. Try this one:

```
function containsSequentialDigits(str) {
    return /01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90|09|98|87|76|65|54|43|32|21|10/.test(str);
}

var s = [
    's',   // false, no digits
    '1x2', // false, no consecutive digits
    '2x1', // false, dito
    '13',  // false, not "sequential"
    '12',  // true, increasing
    '21',  // true, decreasing
];

for( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( s[i], containsSequentialDigits(s[i]) );
}
```

Outputs:

```
"s" false
"1x2" false
"2x1" false
"13" false
"12" true
"21" true
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a simple string of consecutive digits and the `.indexOf()` method.  Assuming that you are looking for ONLY whether or not there are consecutive digits in the string and not what they are, the longest group of consecutive digits, or anything like that (that would take more coding  :)   ), then the following function would work:

```
function hasConsecutiveDigits(sValue) {
    var sConsecutiveDigits = "012345678909876543210";
    var regDigitPattern = /\d{2,}/g;

    var aDigitGroups = sValue.match(regDigitPattern);

    if (aDigitGroups !== null) {
        for (j = 0; j < aDigitGroups.length; j++) {
            for (x = 0; x < (aDigitGroups[j].length - 1); x++) {
                var sCurrDigits = aDigitGroups[j].substring(x, x + 2);
                if (sConsecutiveDigits.indexOf(sCurrDigits) !== -1) {
                    return true;    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The `sConsecutiveDigits` string contains all of the possible consecutive digit patterns, so you can simply capture any group of one or more digits (using the `regDigitPattern` regex value) and then see if any two-digit subgroup of those groups exists as a substring of the `sConsecutiveDigits` string.

Additionally, since you are only looking for "yes, it has consecutive digits" or "no, it does not have consecutive digits", you can exit from the check as soon as you have found a match, cutting down on the processing a little.

I tested the function using the following code:

```
var aTestData = ["ae12", "aeg12345km", "mea65", "ab2d43a21", "poe09ac", "adsas", "asd13sad", "asda1357sd", "sd4dfg3dfg5df"];

for (i = 0; i < aTestData.length; i++) {
    var result = hasConsecutiveDigits(aTestData[i]);

    console.log("'" + aTestData[i] + "' " + ((result) ? "contains" : "does not contain") + " consecutive digits.")
}
```

. . .  and recieved the following results:

```
'ae12' contains consecutive digits.
'aeg12345km' contains consecutive digits.
'mea65' contains consecutive digits.
'ab2d43a21' contains consecutive digits.
'poe09ac' contains consecutive digits.
'adsas' does not contain consecutive digits.
'asd13sad' does not contain consecutive digits.
'asda1357sd' does not contain consecutive digits.
'sd4dfg3dfg5df' does not contain consecutive digits.
```

**UPDATE**

I ran some speed tests on my solution and `Daniel Böhmer`'s here: http://jsperf.com/duplicate-digit-check

Long story, short, they perform pretty similarly across the three prosers that I tested (IE 9, FF 31, and Chrome 40), with a very slight edge to the `indexOf` approach, most of the time.

The fact that all of my code runs as fas as a single regex check gives you an idea of how heavy regex can be.  It's a great tool, but it should be used "gently".   :)

Comment: Nice explanation. But why this complex approach when matching to a regex is enough? Do you see any advantages? Do you have any speed comparisons?

Comment: There were basically two reasons for my approach: (1) as awesome as regex is, it does tend to be a little "process heavy" (though, I have not yet had a chance to speed test these solutions), and (2) the string approach is a little more readable and maintainable than the fairly complex regex patterns that are needed to provide the same solution.  When I get a chance, I'll check the performance.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer - Speed tests added to answer.